# phpmyadmin does not run after installation

Tags: debian, configuration, phpmyadmin

On **Ubuntu 18.04**, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.2 and MySQL installed. 
Afterwards installed phymyadmin, restarted Apache. Expected to be able to run it under `http://localhost/phypmadmin`, but I get a *404*.

There is a file `/etc/phpmydmin/apache.conf` that seems to be supposed to create a Vhost for phpmyadmin, but this file does not seem to be considered by Apache. How do I do that?

Comment: You have tagged this xampp. Are you using the distro native packages or xampp?

Comment: no, I am using the native packages

Answer (score 0):

After installing `phpmyadmin`, if you do not have access to it at http:localhost/phpmyadmin:

- The easiest way to do it is:

  ```
  cd /var/www/html
  sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin phpmyadmin
  ```

After this, you will have access to it.

PS. The installation does not create a vhost for `phpmyadmin`.